# Ruby on Rails: has_many referential --which model objects does it own?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, has-many, model-associations

I am new to Rails and finished Michael Hartl's "Ruby on Rails 3 Tutorial". Although the book teaches me a lot, I find this puzzle I don't understand.

To preview the puzzle, that is, I don't understand, inside User model,

```
has_many :following, :through=>:relationship, :source=>:followed
```

how this piece of code link "user.following" to an array of User instances.

And below is the whole puzzle.

First of all, I have the **Relationship** model, which records **followed_id** and **follower_id** infos. Inside **Relationship** model, the association is simple as

```
class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :followed_id

  belongs_to :follower, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :followed, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Then, inside the User model, a user will assume the role of **follower**, and collect all its **following** rows in relationships table through **relationships** association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  .
  .
  .
  has_many :relationships, :foreign_key => "follower_id", :dependent => :destroy
  .
```

Until now, I got it.

But confusion came at the next line, where through **user.following** it can assemble all that user's following(User instances). Like so,

```
has_many :following, :through=>:relationships, :source=>:followed
```

I understand that **:source=>:followed** will overwrite the default, and let find all **followed_ids** associated with that user.

**But**, how can Rails recognize **followed_id** to link to **User** object? The label name doesn't match **users**, nor is there **:class_name** specified. I just don't get how Rails do this underlying work, or I missed out some hints.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, how can Rails recognize followed_id to link to User object? The
>   label name doesn't match users, nor is there :class_name specified. I
>   just don't get how Rails do this underlying work, or I missed out some
>   hints.

Rails recognize that is an user object because it is set in Relationship's belongs_to. What Rails does here is to follow the relationship class through the foreign key "follower_id" and returning every User that has a relationship with the current user as followed. Of course Rails do that in a single SQL statement like this:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `relationships` ON `relationships`.followed_id = `users`.id WHERE ((`relationships`.follower_id = <the current user id>  ))
```

Comment: Can I interpret that, the association with Relationship model through `belongs_to`, is successful because User has `:source=>:followed`, and Relationship also defines `belongs_to :followed`?

Comment: Exactly, rails knows that it's an User because of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
has_many :following, :through=>:relationships, :source=>:followed
```

This explains to Rails that `following` is the inverse relationship of `following` and that users has many following and followed through his relationships.

The way Rails knows that `followed_id` is linked to User is that it is defined in your `Relationship` model.

Hope you've understood ! Good luck :)